# Conditionally Set Values Greater Than 0 To 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this, with many more date columns

```
              AUTHOR        2022-07-01  2022-10-14      2022-10-15 .....
0            Kathrine          0.0         7.0              0.0
1            Catherine         0.0         13.0             17.0
2            Amanda Jane       0.0         0.0              0.0
3            Jaqueline         0.0         3.0              0.0
4            Christine         0.0         0.0              0.0
```

I would like to set values in each column after the `AUTHOR` to 1 when the value is greater than 0, so the resulting table would look like this:

```
              AUTHOR        2022-07-01  2022-10-14      2022-10-15 .....
0            Kathrine          0.0         1.0              0.0
1            Catherine         0.0         1.0              1.0
2            Amanda Jane       0.0         0.0              0.0
3            Jaqueline         0.0         1.0              0.0
4            Christine         0.0         0.0              0.0
```

I tried the following line of code but got an error, which makes sense. As I need to figure out how to apply this code just to the date columns while also keeping the `AUTHOR` column in my table.

```
Counts[Counts != 0] = 1


TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the date column first then mask on these columns

```py
cols = df.drop(columns='AUTHOR').columns
# or
cols = df.filter(regex='\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}').columns
# or
cols = df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns

df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols] != 0, 1)
```

```
print(df)

        AUTHOR  2022-07-01  2022-10-14  2022-10-15
0     Kathrine         0.0         1.0         0.0
1    Catherine         0.0         1.0         1.0
2  Amanda Jane         0.0         0.0         0.0
3    Jaqueline         0.0         1.0         0.0
4    Christine         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you would like to only exclude the first column you could first set it as index and then create your booleans. In the end you will reset the index.

```
df.set_index('AUTHOR').pipe(lambda g: g.mask(g > 0, 1)).reset_index()
df

     AUTHOR  2022-10-14  2022-10-15
0  Kathrine         0.0         1.0
1  Cathrine         1.0         1.0
```